# Forcing ggplot to use only one colour for fill/color statement

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=rnorm(10), C=rnorm(10), D=rnorm(10))
df.melt <- melt(df, id="A")
```

plotting without specifying the color in aesthestics gives one line:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df.melt, aes(x=A, y=value))
```

but i want to have the three variables separated:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df.melt, aes(x=A, y=value, colour=variable))
```

but with one color!

My solution is to define a color palette with all black,

```
col <- rep("black", 3)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df.melt, aes(x=A, y=value, colour=variable)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=col) +
  guides(color=FALSE)
```

but i wonder if there is a built-in solution?

Comment: Specify color outside the `aes` call, e.g. `geom_line(data = df.melt, aes(...), color = "red")`.

Comment: use `group=variable` instead of `colour=variable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group=variable` rather than `colour=variable`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=rnorm(10), C=rnorm(10), D=rnorm(10))
df.melt <- melt(df, id="A")

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df.melt, aes(x=A, y=value, group=variable)) +
  guides(color=FALSE)
```

[image]